# SWAP increasing during network traffic

Tags: networking, hard-drive, swap

I have a huge HDD with `/home` mounted and a small SSD with `/` and `swap` (6GB for the latter, 5.7GB shown in Ubuntu 15.04).

From another computer, I initiated writing into my HDD. I intend to transfer about 250GB via my 100Mb/s ethernet connection. The files are large enough which leads to the fact that the network is used almost optimally (usually around 100%, seldom 99%).

After a while I noticed that the swap partition (on my computer - the destination of the transfer) is becoming more full (about 20% right now). When I pause the transfer, the percentage stagnates.

I assume that my HDD can't handle the load of incoming data and the swap is used in order to maintain the transfer speed.

I expect that when I pause the transfer, the swap percentage will decrease slowly. **But it doesn't.**

So I kindly ask for some answers to my questions:

1. What happens when the swap partition is full? Will the transfer speed be automatically decreased in order to make HDD comfortable? Will the computer reboot? Or freeze?
2. If the transfer finishes **before** the swap is full, will it empty itself and store the data to the HDD? If not, what should I do?
3. Can I command the network card (or some deamon maybe?) to accept the packets more slowly? If so, how?
4. Can I force the system to move data from swap to HDD when the transfer is paused? If so, how?

Comment: I am no swap expert, but first, it should not be located on an SSD, especially not an older one, as those only support a small amount of write cycles before they die, whereas swap requires many of them. Second, there is some difference between allocated swap and used swap. The system displays how much swap space is allocated, but that does not mean all of it is still in use (don't ask me why). I think you should not worry about that. And swapping data back into memory is done when the data is needed again, I think, not as soon as enough RAM becomes free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that since the data you are transferring are written in memory through DMA from your network card, and then stored to disk again using DMA (i.e. memory regions that cannot get swapped), the kernel just swaps pages from other applications, which is normal and, imho, shouldn't alarm you.

1. When system cannot allocate any memory theoretically it terminates processes to free memory (I don't know the algorithm that it uses to choose which ones). Practically system freezes and/or panics in my experience.
2. When transfer is complete, swap data will be read back to memory when needed.
3. You can turn off the swap and then turn it on again using swapon and swapoff commands.

Comment: Thanks! The transfer has finished before swap was full. Afterwards the usage of swap slowly decreased as new applications were launched. Hence I assume you are right!